# Git commands to pull latest and push to local

Tags: git, github

Please correct me on any of the following:

Let's assume I have a remote origin which is my local forked repo and a remote upstream which is let's say production.

Starting from step one:

After git clone, I have no branches on my forked repo, except main (or master, whatever's the "main" one from the upstream).

To create a branch on my local, I'll do:

```
git checkout -b <branch>
```

This'll create a branch in working tree (not my local repo)

To grab everything from upstream, I'll run:

```
git pull upstream <branch>
```

This'll merge all the code from that branch into my working tree branch (essentially getting me completely up to date on my working tree?)

My local repo isn't updated, so I'll run:

```
git push origin?
```

This'll add the branch to my local repo, along with the most updated code I received from the previous command?

This is my understanding, if I'm completely wrong please tell me but also explain why. Just want to learn once and for all how to correctly fetch latest and push commits.

Comment: `git checkout -b <branch>` changes your local repo, as do most git commands.  It does nothing to your working tree.  You don't ever "push" to your local repo.  You push to remote repos.  `git pull` merges the remote repo into your local repo, and then updates your working tree from the local repo.

Comment: Sorry I'm confusing working tree and local repo. When you say local repo, you're referring to the forked repo? In that case, git checkout -b <branch> will automatically add that branch to my local repo?

Comment: Yes.  That's the entire purpose of that command.  There are really only a few key concepts to grokking `git`; the whole working vs local vs remote distinction happens to be one of the key concepts.  And that, mostly, you can screw up your working tree in almost any way imaginable, because you can always checkout from your local repo.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying that. Can you confirm the rest by any chance? Will git pull upstream <branch> update my local repo and working dir with the latest code> (assuming I didn't make any changes to either so not mentioning merge or rebase issues)

Comment: The documentation helps here.  `git pull` is the same as `git fetch` and `git checkout`.  `git fetch` copies from the remote repo to the local repo.  `git checkout` updates the working tree.  However, if you have created a new branch that has the same name as an upstream branch, that's a conflict.  You need to do the pull first.